# Adding a global custom attribute in the assembly with Cecil

Tags: c#, mono, assemblies, mono.cecil

I have got this attribute class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
public class PostProcessedAssemblyAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

and then wrote this code:

```
var moduleG = assembly.MainModule;

            var attributeConstructor =
                    moduleG.ImportReference(
                        typeof(PostProcessedAssemblyAttribute).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
            var attribute = new CustomAttribute(attributeConstructor);
            assembly.CustomAttributes.Add(attribute);

 assembly.Write(assemblyPath, writerParameters);
```

if I read back the assembly, I expect the attribute to be present, but it is not.

I am not 100% sure of what I am doing, so surely I am doing something wrong (for example I am not sure importing the attribute from the main module is correct), can you please point out where the problem is?

I need this just to mark an assembly as processed.

Comment: The code here works fine for me. Could you include a more complete example, that shows relationships between the assemblies here and how you're reading the assembly afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works indeed, it was my mistake to look for the attribute just using assembly.CustomAttributes.Contains which can't work at all. Eventually I solved it creating a TypeReference from the actual Type and check the CustomAttribute.AttributeType.FullName against the FullName of the TypeReference I need to check.